# Circular reference error when bundling with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm converting a Typescript project, which uses `module/namespace` syntax and `triple slash directive`, so that it will use `ES6 import` syntax instead. The project used the `tsc` command to transpile the code, but that will be changed to use Webpack.

I have successfully switch over so it builds with Webpack. And I'm slowly in progress to replace the way to import modules into the newer ES6 syntax.

It worked quite well, but now I get this error, which I deducted it is most likely due to circular references.

[image]

I looked up why this wasn't a problem prior to the change to use `import` over `triple slash directive`, and it seems to be that when using triple slash you basically tells Typescript you want to concatenate the files in the order you have put the directive. While in the Webpack case it would require the files.

Anyhow I'm wondering does Webpack has some plugin which would build the bundle so that circular reference is found and fixed? Short answer is possibly no, but I'm trying my luck!

**Update**

As suggested by @AluanHaddad I changed target to `ESNext` in `tsconfig.json`. And I get the following error now instead. I guess this is the same error message, but it is now more clear on what the issue is perhaps?

[image]

To give this error message some context.

I have a class which looks something as following. And it seems like when Button is required/called the inherited call has not been initiated. How can that happen?

```
export class Button extends Component { ... }
```

Comment: The viability of circular references depends on the module format. Transpile to es next modules and let webpack handle the import statements and it should be fine. If you're targeting common JS modules you're going to run into issues. Triple / references are so different from modules that it's not even comparable

Comment: @AluanHaddad I changed `tsconfig.json` file as you suggested so it targets `ESNext` I get a different error now instead. I have updated my question with the error.

Comment: I'd like to assist you, but I don't have enough information. Can you post a minimal amount of code to reproduce the error?